# MD5 collision may happen for input of 18 chars?

Tags: md5

have anyone proved or tested that whether or not MD5 collision may happen  for data with fixed length of 18 bytes ?

i.e. can I construct two arrays(18 bytes length) with same MD5?

thanks!

Comment: The question is not if it will happen - of course it will, _eventually_ - but how long it would take.

Comment: 18 bytes is 144 bits of information. An MD5 hash is 128 bits of information.  Therefore it is not possible for every combination of 18 characters to have a unique MD5 hash.

Comment: Great!  thanks for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that MD5 has a length of 16 bytes... yes, 18 byte values are *guaranteed* to collide eventually.

But it's the wrong question to ask. Hashes are by definition prone to collisions. It *may* even happen with two single byte values. Very unlikely, but *possible*. If you're using a hash, you ***must expect*** collisions to happen. The question is whether this is acceptable for your use case, what implications a collision has for your application, whether you can mitigate that problem, and how *likely* it is for a collision to happen.

All this together informs your decision whether hashing in general is something you want to use in your situation and/or what hash in particular to choose.